# NewtonSoft StreamingContext conflict with Microsoft .Net framework mscorlib.dll

Tags: .net, sharepoint, json.net

I added Newtonsoft 3.5 compact dll in one of SharePoint project and while building the project i am getting following error.

`Error  9   The type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext' exists in both 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll' and 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Newtonsoft.Json.Compact\3.5.0.0__30ad4fe6b2a6aeed\Newtonsoft.Json.Compact.dll'   E:\Projects\Khagesh\PE-TFS\Solutions\Exceptions\Exception.cs`

By removing reference of Newtonsoft, this error does not come. However, i need both the DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed `Newtonsoft.Json.Compact.dll` and added `Newtonsoft.Json.Net20.dll` and everything works fine. I have no idea why these two dlls are there and when to use which one.